# Unable to access query string parameters in Flask app production server

Tags: python, flask

I have a small Flask app which I’ve built and everything is working as intended on my local development version. However, when I deploy to a production server it doesn’t seem to be receiving any query string parameters at all — they all return `null` when I check for them.

This is some example code I wrote to test and explain the issue:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

# Home route
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
  return '<h1>Home</h1>'

# Test route
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def test():
  return jsonify(request.args.get('name')), 200
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

This is just being used to test and debug the issue on the server. The intended behaviour is that when you visit `https://websiteurl.com/test?name=John` you should receive `'John'` back. However I always receive `null`.

Even when I try to return all query parameters by using `return jsonify(request.args), 200` I just receive a blank json object: `{}`. It seems odd that this works perfectly in development but not at all in production which leads me to believe I’ve missed something obvious that the production server requires?

I’m also aware that I shouldn’t be using `app.run()` for a production server, but I’m just using this to test at the moment.

Comment: Your snippet works in my case...

Comment: I have tested on another server and can confirm it’s working so it must be something wrong with the configuration of this one. Will be interesting to know what it is

Comment: If this is on a remote server, then probably the firewall is blocking/modifying the requests (I mean here firewall in a broad meaning, namely any software likely to modify entering requests, including nginx, iptable, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Specify a static URL, request, redirect, etc.
Also check your server specifications, file encoding differences, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I have tested on another server and can confirm it’s working so it must be something wrong with the configuration of this one. Will be interesting to know what it is